# Limit of a sequence - product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Any idea how to compute the following limit:
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(2-2^{1/2})(2-2^{1/3})...(2-2^{1/n})$?
I would be very grateful to see a solution/hint to this problem!
I have yet no idea how to approach this.

Comment: In case it helps, the limit is 0. And it may be easier to work with $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log(2-2^\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

A start: $2^{1/k} = e^{(\ln 2)/k} > 1 + (\ln 2)/k.$ Thus the $k$th factor is less than $1-(\ln2)/k).$ Letting $p_n$ denote your product above, we have

$$\ln p_n <\sum_{k=2}^{n} \ln (1-(\ln2)/k)).$$